# Starting vscode directly in remote ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut-file, vscode-remote

I'm using vscode remote ssh heavily and each time, I have to start it regularly and and run the commmand to start a new instance with Remote SSH

Is there a way to use some arguments to VsCode shortcut to start directly in Remote SSH mode?

Thanks

Comment: you got any workaround on this?

Comment: See answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

Found this link that includes a section about connecting to a remote from terminal (or using a shortcut)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_connect-to-a-remote-host-from-the-terminal

SSH remote needs to already have been manually setup (ssh config file and public/private key).